# Вставка изображение в HTML страницу в проекте ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, изображения

Необходимо помощь, со вставкой изображения в HTML. Проект на ASP.NET MVC, изображения хранятся в папке wwwroot/Images/CarIcon. Пытаюсь добавить ссылку на изображение следующим образом:

```
@foreach (var car in Model)
    {
        var pathToImage = "~/Images/CarIcon/Sedan.jpg";
        var alttext = "Sedan";
        if (car.BodyType != InWayLibrary.Models.CarBodyTypes.NotExist)
        {
            alttext = car.BodyType.ToString();
            pathToImage = $"~/Images/CarIcon/{car.BodyType}.jpg";
        }
        <div class="line_block_h">
            <form class="form-input" method="post" action="update">
                <img src=@pathToImage alt = "@alttext" style="width:300px;height:200px;">
                /*
                   
                */
            </form>
        </div>
    }
```

При размещении изображения на Index, оно отображается:

```
<img src="~/Images/CarIcon/Sedan.jpg" class="img" alt="InWay" />
```

При этом адрес, который отображается в debagtools:

```
https://localhost:7065/Images/CarIcon/Sedan.jpg
```

Но если я перехожу через контроллер на другую станицу, то тот же путь к файлу прописывается как:

```
https://localhost:7065/car/~/Images/CarIcon/Sedan.jpg
```

и соответственно картинка не отображается

Comment: [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: по-моему тильду стоит убрать ~ //wwwroot это статические файлы ....статический контекст помещается в папку web root или корневую папку для веб-контента, которая по умолчанию назвается wwwroot. в блазор принцип из аспНет взят https://metanit.com/sharp/blazor/2.1.php